# Issues with files type list declaration

Tags: python, database, list, dataframe, compiler-errors

My problem is after executing my python script I get an error and I just can't figure out what the mistake is!
here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io
import os
import csv
import sys
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import time
import pylab
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.artist as artists
from matplotlib.pyplot import savefig
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D


# S'assurer de bien mettre le chemain vers le fichier data souhaite et le modifier si besoin : ici les tack MW pour M=9Msoleil
data = "/home/Desktop/MW/BoOST-stellarmodels-MW/f009-100.mw.dat"

#indexes des colonnes
Nom = "/home/Desktop/MW/BoOST-stellarmodels-MW/fdat-columns.txt"
    
# Open a dataframe that contains the file root

f = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\t', decimal = '.', engine = 'python') 

# Open a Dataframe for the head row that is in a separate file

Headers = pd.read_csv (Nom, index_col = 0, nrows = 0, sep ='\t').columns.values.tolist()

Columns = ['status']
#Combine the two Dataframes into one file that contains all the datas

Res = pd.read_csv(Headers, usecols = Columns, sep = '\t').to_csv('f', index = False)


#Write a .dat file to visualise the results

print (Headers)   #Terminal

open ('Tracks.dat', 'wb')
Res.to_csv ('Tracks.dat', sep = '\t', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

The error that occurs is :

```
File "essai", line 36, in <module>
    Res = pd.read_csv(Headers, usecols = Columns, sep = '\t').to_csv('f', index = False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 424, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 218, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <type 'list'>
```

I don't know if it's a path problem, or if the list is not well declared....
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the first parameter at this line:

> Res = pd.read_csv(**Headers**, usecols = Columns, sep = '\t').to_csv('f', index = False)

As mentioned in [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), the first parameter of read_csv() should be *str, path object or file-like object*, while you passed a list (Headers)

Comment: yes i see it now, but i don't know what else to use in order to combine those two folders....

Answer (score 0):

a litle update, i have tried with `Pd.read_fwf`it works well!